# Banned IPs in Django form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to validate a form, such that if IP of user (`request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`) is   in a table `BlockedIPs`, it would fail validation. However I don't have access to `request` variable in `Form`. How do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make it available to your form by overriding `__init__` so it can be passed in during construction (or you could just pass the IP itself):

```
from django import forms

class YourForm(forms.Form)
    # fields...

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # validation methods...
```

Now you just need to pass the `request` object as the first argument when initialising the form and your custom validation methods will have access to it through `self.request`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = YourForm(request, request.POST)
    # ...
else:
    form = YourForm(request)
# ...
```